# Powershell and SQL Connection String Error

Tags: powershell, connection-string, sqlconnection

```
function GenericSqlQuery($ConnectionString, $SQLQuery) {
    Write-Host $ConnectionString
    $Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
    $Connection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
    $Connection.Open()
    $Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
    $Command.Connection = $Connection
    $Command.CommandText = $SQLQuery
    $Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader()
    while ($Reader.Read()) {
         $Reader.GetValue(0)
    }
    $Connection.Close()
}
```

See the above, the `$Connectionstring` is replaced ok when the `Write-Host` is executed but when the `$Connection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString` is executed it does not get replaced and the script errors with the following

```
Exception setting "ConnectionString": "Format of the initialization string does not conform to 
specification starting at index 64."
At C:\Users\Blah\Desktop\Debugger\ABS9_DB_Update.ps1:7 char:5
+     **$Connection.ConnectionString = "$ConnectionString"**
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
```

Anyone know why?

Tried all sorts of combinations but I cannot get anything to work. The following had the same issue

```
$Connection.ConnectionString = "server='$Server';database='$Database';trusted_connection=true;"
```

I even tried

```
$Connection.ConnectionString = "server='"+$Server+"';database='"+$Database+"';trusted_connection=true;" 

$Connection.ConnectionString="server='"+"$Server"+"';database='"+"$Database"+"';trusted_connection=true;"
```

But none of the variables get replaced.

Comment: Firstly, never use screenshots; it is unlikely that anyone will help without being able to copy the code. Secondly, there is an error in your string format - you are using single quotes. Variables in single quotes aren't replaced with a value. Try `$ConnectionString = "server=$Server;database=$Database;trusted_connection=true"`

Comment: Don't put the connection string elements in single quotes. it's **not** `"Server='$server';..."`. Instead, it's just `"Server=$server;..."`

Comment: Also, this method will force you to build up SQL commands in unsafe ways. Sometimes, with scripts, that's okay, as you know the source of any inputs. But if the script will run interactively to get input values, or if you'll do things like load data from csv files where the data originates from user input, this is **very bad**, and you should look at adding an additional argument to the method to accept query parameter information.

Comment: I am new to powershell and what I have is a form that connects to an instance of SQL and then it needs to check if a particular table in the database has a specific field and I am building the query to do that and want to execute the query.

Comment: Same issue even if I use what was suggested, ie,     

$Connection.ConnectionString = "server=$Server;database=$Database;trusted_connection=true"

Comment: Maybe obvious but did you create variables for $Server and $Database? And what is your connection string and what kind of database are you connecting to?

Comment: The variables are setup correctly and the connection is to a SQL 2019 database. The connection is not the issue but the issue is that the variables are not replaced with their values, so  for example $Server stays as $Server and not as Localhost if I set it to that.

Elsewhere in the script the same variables are replaced it is just the ConnectionString where they are not,

Comment: I figured it out, the values were coming from text boxes on the GUI form and I simply needed to reference with the .Text property like   $Connection.ConnectionString = "server="+$SQLServer.text+";database="+$SQLDatabase.text

Comment: @Robert Don't forget to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you found a solution :)

Comment: @Robert Then you can do this: `$Connection.ConnectionString = "server=$($SQLServer.Text);database=$($SQLDatabase.Text);..."`, without all that concatenation

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the values were coming from text boxes on the GUI form and I simply needed to reference with the .Text property like $Connection.ConnectionString = "server="+$SQLServer.text+";database="+$SQLDatabase.text

Comment: If this solution fixed your problem you should mark it as the answer.  Also, you should pay attention to the warnings in the comments about the risks of injection - i assume as your writing a GUI people other than you will use it, so the chance of incorrect input (or even malicious input) is much higher. I would recommended you put some simple error checking in your code to prevent potential problems. Simple checks like string length or using a regex to validate the input is always a good idea and makes your code safer and less prone to errors.

Comment: Yes other people will use this and it is updating there own non production SQL database which only them and admin have access to
There are only fields on the GUI to do the connection, so the only fields are SQLServer, SQLDatabase and SQLSchema which are parameters for the INVOKE-SQLCMD (changed it to use this). The queries it runs are hardcoded and not passed as an input from the GUI